# Can Perfmon be used to monitor free space on a (mounted) SMB share?

Tags: monitoring, windows, server-message-block, perfmon

Is there a way to use Windows Perfmon to monitor available space on a (mounted) SMB share?

For example: on server `ABC`, I'd have a share `\\DEF\SharedFiles` mounted. As I can't set up any monitoring on server `DEF`, I'd like to use Perfmon to watch the free space available on the `SharedFiles` share located on server `DEF`.

SMB shares don't seem to appear to be reported by the `LogicalDisk` counters, while I don't see any counter in `SMB Client Shares` that could be used to report free space.

Comment: you could just use perfmon to remotely monitor the counters directly on the DEF server.

Comment: @Rex I have access to the share on `DEF`, but not to the machine itself and likely unable to access these counters remotely (must be part of the Performance Monitor Users group or have administrative privileges). Also, this would require me to know where the share is located (in case of multiple disks on server `DEF`)

Comment: If you need to monitor the space - then either work with the admin to monitor the space or ask them for the permissions to do so. Other than that, I don't think perfmon is your solution. There are other utilities that can do this however, as well as some powershell/vbscript that can be scheduled every x minutes to report on the space and notify on a specific threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do what you want using Performance Monitor.

Traditionally, you'd do this by accessing the LogicalDisk counters on the `DEF` machine remotely. Since you state in your comments that you don't have access to the performance counters on the `DEF` machine that's a non-starter.

There is no performance counter that exposes free space on remote shares being accessed with SMB.

I think you're stuck writing a script.